# How to get horizontal scroll and auto-sizing in "Python Console"?

Tags: pycharm

I was wondering if someone could please help with a couple "Python Console" issues I'm having with version 2016.1.2.  In both cases I'm using the "Floating Mode" option of the console.

(1)
The first issue is when I first launch a console it seems like the input line does not keep up with the display until I resize the window manually.  So for example, here is a screenshot of the console when I first launch it and then after I resize it:

[image: PyCharm Screenshot]

So what happens is that the interactive input line initially does not move down far enough to show all of the text. It stays "stuck" here until I resize the window.

(2)
The second issue is easier to explain.  When I display a pandas data frame that is very wide, it seems that the horizontal scroll bar does not appear.  I'm not sure if there's a setting to enable "horizontal scroll in console" but in the previous versions of PyCharm the scroll bar would just appear when there was output that went beyond the window size.

As an aside, I like to display very wide pandas data frames since it's easier to read across than try to have the output wrap down vertically.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a regression. The horizontal scroll in the console worked fine one or two versions ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I updated to community edition 2016.1.3 build #PC-145.971 today and horizontal scrolling in the console works again.

Comment: Updated as well and found that it works now too. Thanks.